# Отладка лямбда-функций

Tags: c#, lambda

Скажите, есть ли в Visual Studio какие-то возможности выполнять отладку кода, содержащего лямбда-функции? Отладчик при попытках прогнать через него такой кодругается благим матом. Может, имеются какие-то соответствующие расширения для студии?

Comment: покажи функцию, хочется глянуть, что там можно отлаживать?)

Comment: хм..речь не о конкретной функции

Comment: А что именно не выходит? Для вот такой функции:

    Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                throw new Exception("test");
        });

на строке с throw можно поставить breakpoint, попробуйте!

Comment: извиняюсь, наверное ,неверно сформулировал. Я имею в виду, что в окне "Watch" (и "Quick Watch" соответственно) нельзя просматривать результаты выполнения кода, содержащего лямбды (а также LINQ-запросы)

Comment: @DreamChild: а, это да. И в окне Immediate тоже. Я думаю, это общая проблема Visual Studio. Надеюсь, в VS 2012 они это исправили.

Comment: к сожалению, не пофиксили - приходилось писать и в VS 12

Comment: @DreamChild: упс :( Я для таких случаев держу в отдельном экземпляре студии маленький тестовый консольный проект и отлаживаю на нём. Не айс, конечно.

Comment: тестовый проект я тоже держу, правда, не в отдельном экземпляре, но все равно хочется большего

Comment: Чтобы понять, что у вас ни так, напишите. что конкретно за ошибка вылазит? Никогда не встречался с проблемой в лямбда выражениях. Может у вас проблема в чем то другом?






___________________________________________
maxhammer.ru - профессиональное обучение C# 

Comment: это у вас SEO что ли?

Comment: спасибо за внимание, но я уже получил информацию по данному вопросу из обсуждения в комментариях

Comment: а что касается этого вашего чудо-сайта, то "профессиональное обучение C#" - это громко сказано. Оооочень громко. Без обид, но это уроки от школьника для школьников. Написанные, к тому же, не слишком грамотным человеком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь приведены возможные варианты отладки: [Фильтрация коллекций в отладочных окнах Visual Studio](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122573/)